# Spinner not working on Safari

Tags: jquery, cookies, safari

I have an spinner image, shown on button click.In the click event I generate a token and I set up window.location.href to a path that generates a file for download. This generated token is sent in backend and when the file is generated and the download starts, this token is compared with an cookie that's generated with jquery cookie and based on the same token I mentioned.

On chrome, when the download starts, I hide the spinner. It's working fine. But on Safari, when I click the button, file begins to be generated, but the spinner is displayed 1,2 seconds earlier than download start. Note: the generating process is between 10-15 seconds.

```js
$('body').on('click', '#export-drops', function(e) {
        $.removeCookie('token');
        spinner.show();
        e.preventDefault();
        
        var token = new Date().getTime();
        window.location.href = "{{ request.path }}?export=excel&token=" + token;

        timer = window.setInterval(function() {
            var cookieValue = $.cookie('token');
            if (cookieValue == token) {
                window.clearInterval(timer);
                $.removeCookie('token');
                spinner.hide();
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Comment: drop the spinner code in here my friend

Answer (score 0):

Look at first post @madalin-ivascu